Gazebo process dies instantly and not able to load URDF file of the robot in ROS2
I have migrated a project from ROS1 to ROS2 where there is a simulation of a robot with a room and a table and a robot. I have a launch file in python that loads these models in Gazebo and runs another launch file that deals with the configuration file for that robot. I use Moveit2 for path planning. Below I will show my launch file, and configuration file an the error that I am receiving.
Mainly, this launch file is the first of 3 launch files that needs to run to have the full simulation in Gazebo and Rviz, however, I am not able to run the second and third files since the Gazebo process dies instantly for some reason. And I am receiving another error that one of my configuration parameters cannot be realized.
Here is my launch file:
import os
import launch
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription, ExecuteProcess
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import launch.logging


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = LaunchDescription()

    # Arguments
 

    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('paused', default_value='false'))
    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('gazebo_gui', default_value='true'))
    ld.add_action(DeclareLaunchArgument('urdf_path', default_value= os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_model'), 'urdf', 'mtr.urdf')))
    urdf_path = LaunchConfiguration('urdf_path')
    #logger = launch.logging.get_logger('launch')
    #logger.info(f'Package share directory for ysio_model: {get_package_share_directory('ysio_model')}')
    #logger.info(f'Package share directory for ysio_model: {get_package_share_directory('ysio_moveit_config')}')

    
    

    # Use Gazebo's empty world template and import objects created in world file as well as models into the simulation environment
    ld.add_action(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), '/launch/gazebo.launch.py']),
            launch_arguments={
                'world': os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation') , 'worlds' , 'simulation.world'),
                'verbose': 'true',
                'paused': LaunchConfiguration('paused'),
                'gui': LaunchConfiguration('gazebo_gui'),
                'use_sim_time': 'true'
            }.items()
        )
    )

    # Spawn room and bed models using spawn_entity.py
    ld.add_action(
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'room', '-x', '0', '-y', '0.8475', '-z', '1.4', '-file',
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation'), 'models', 'Scan_Room', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        )
    )
    ld.add_action(
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'bed', '-z', '0.375', '-Y', '1.57', '-file', 
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_simulation'), 'models', 'PatientBed', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        )
    )
    
    # Spawn robot in Gazebo using spawn_entity.py
    ld.add_action(
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'robot', '-x', '0', '-y', '0', '-z', '0', '-file', urdf_path],
            output='screen'
        )
    )
    # Launch robot_state_publisher to publish the robot state using the URDF
    ld.add_action(
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            name='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'robot_description': urdf_path}]
        )
    )



    # Initialize PID controllers
    ld.add_action(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_moveit_config'),'launch', 'ros_controllers.launch.py')])
        )
    )

    # Initialize MoveIt for motion planning
    ld.add_action(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ysio_moveit_config'),'launch', 'move_group.launch.py')])
        )
    )

    return ld

and here is my configuration file:
 Simulation settings for using moveit_sim_controllers
moveit_sim_hw_interface:
  joint_model_group: YSIO
  joint_model_group_pose: home
# Settings for ros_control_boilerplate control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01
# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - fixed
    - RadTubeLongitudinal
    - RadTubeLift
    - RadTubeRotVertical
    - RadTubeRotHorizontal
    - CollimatorRotA
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity
# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  name: YSIO::joint_state_controller
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - name: YSIO::ysio_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - fixed
      - RadTubeLongitudinal
      - RadTubeLift
      - RadTubeRotVertical
      - RadTubeRotHorizontal
      - CollimatorRotA
ysio_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - fixed
    - RadTubeLongitudinal
    - RadTubeLift
    - RadTubeRotVertical
    - RadTubeRotHorizontal
    - CollimatorRotA
  gains:
    fixed:
      p: 200.0
      d: 60.0
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1
    RadTubeLongitudinal:
      p: 200.0
      d: 60
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1
    RadTubeLift:
      p: 200.0
      d: 60.0
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1
    RadTubeRotVertical:
      p: 200.0
      d: 160.0
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1
    RadTubeRotHorizontal:
      p: 100.0
      d: 50.0
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1
    CollimatorRotA:
      p: 100.0
      d: 10
      i: 0.01
      i_clamp: 1

and here is the error that I am getting when I run the launch file: As you can see in the error, first i have a problem with realizing one of the parameters from the configuration file, then I have a problem in spawning the bed entity (which sometimes appear and sometimes not, in the end the bed and room are just very simple entities) and I have a problem in parsing the URDF file for the robot, it says that the urdf file is empty but it is not. and then the gazebo process dies,if someone has a suggestion on why this problem appears, I would really appreciate it.
ros@ros:~/test_mig_ws/src$ ros2 launch rdds_kem123_test_package simulation_moveit.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ros/.ros/log/2024-06-12-10-50-45-876929-ros-305713
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=RuntimeError("Failed to handle type {'name': 'YSIO::ysio_controller', 'action_ns': 'follow_joint_trajectory', 'default': True, 'type': 'FollowJointTrajectory', 'joints': ['fixed', 'RadTubeLongitudinal', 'RadTubeLift', 'RadTubeRotVertical', 'RadTubeRotHorizontal', 'CollimatorRotA']}")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 45, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    futures_to_return += visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(sub_entity, context)
  [Previous line repeated 3 more times]
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/load_composable_nodes.py", line 209, in execute
    load_node_requests = [
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/load_composable_nodes.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
    get_composable_node_load_request(node_description, context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/actions/load_composable_nodes.py", line 264, in get_composable_node_load_request
    param.to_parameter_msg() for param in to_parameters_list(
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/to_parameters_list.py", line 49, in to_parameters_list
    context, normalize_parameter_dict(yaml.safe_load(f))
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/normalize_parameters.py", line 164, in normalize_parameter_dict
    normalized[tuple(name)] = _normalize_parameter_array_value(value)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch_ros/utilities/normalize_parameters.py", line 71, in _normalize_parameter_array_value
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to handle type {}'.format(repr(subvalue)))
RuntimeError: Failed to handle type {'name': 'YSIO::ysio_controller', 'action_ns': 'follow_joint_trajectory', 'default': True, 'type': 'FollowJointTrajectory', 'joints': ['fixed', 'RadTubeLongitudinal', 'RadTubeLift', 'RadTubeRotVertical', 'RadTubeRotHorizontal', 'CollimatorRotA']}
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-28' coro=<LaunchService._process_one_event() done, defined at /opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py:226> exception=RuntimeError('Signal event received before subprocess transport available.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 228, in _process_one_event
    await self.__process_event(next_event)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/launch_service.py", line 248, in __process_event
    visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures(entity, self.__context))
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/utilities/visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures_impl.py", line 38, in visit_all_entities_and_collect_futures
    sub_entities = entity.visit(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/action.py", line 108, in visit
    return self.execute(context)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/opaque_function.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.__function(context, *self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_process.py", line 443, in __on_signal_process_event
    raise RuntimeError('Signal event received before subprocess transport available.')
RuntimeError: Signal event received before subprocess transport available.
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [305725]
[INFO] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: process started with pid [305727]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process started with pid [305730]
[INFO] [ros2-4]: process started with pid [305733]
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process started with pid [305735]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-6]: process started with pid [305737]
[INFO] [ros2-5]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-5]
[INFO] [ros2-4]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-4]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[ros2-3]
[INFO] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[gzclient --verbose  -2]
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGINT' to process[gzserver-1]
[gzserver-1] Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
[gzserver-1] Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
[gzserver-1] Released under the Apache 2 License.
[gzserver-1] http://gazebosim.org
[gzserver-1] 
[gzclient --verbose  -2] Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
[gzclient --verbose  -2] Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
[gzclient --verbose  -2] Released under the Apache 2 License.
[gzclient --verbose  -2] http://gazebosim.org
[gzclient --verbose  -2] 
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.183256625] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.183746649] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_simulation/share/ysio_simulation/models/Scan_Room/model.sdf
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.185680742] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.186105928] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[ros2-4] [INFO] [1718182247.184756170] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[ros2-4] [INFO] [1718182247.185233911] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_simulation/share/ysio_simulation/models/PatientBed/model.sdf
[ros2-4] [INFO] [1718182247.187078597] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[ros2-4] [INFO] [1718182247.187503213] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182247.180417624] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182247.180915076] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_model/share/ysio_model/urdf/mtr.urdf
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182247.185699889] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182247.186133098] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[robot_state_publisher-6] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-6] Error:   Error document empty.
[robot_state_publisher-6]          at line 71 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-urdfdom-2.3.3/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
[robot_state_publisher-6] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[robot_state_publisher-6]   what():  Unable to initialize urdf::model from robot description
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.441381746] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182247.441958500] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[ros2-4] [INFO] [1718182247.443014631] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[ERROR] [robot_state_publisher-6]: process has died [pid 305737, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher --ros-args -r __node:=robot_state_publisher --params-file /tmp/launch_params_ft_fsbbn'].
[ros2-3] [INFO] [1718182247.673117613] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [room]
[INFO] [ros2-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 305730]
[gzserver-1] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzserver-1] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzserver-1] [Msg] Publicized address: 10.42.21.233
[gzserver-1] [Msg] Loading world file [/home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_simulation/share/ysio_simulation/worlds/simulation.world]
[gzserver-1] [Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[gzserver-1] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so: libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] [Err] [Plugin.hh:212] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so: libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] [Wrn] [ModelDatabase.cc:340] Getting models from[http://models.gazebosim.org/]. This may take a few seconds.
[ros2-5] [INFO] [1718182248.178857140] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [robot]
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process has finished cleanly [pid 305735]
[gzclient --verbose  -2] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzclient --verbose  -2] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzclient --verbose  -2] [Msg] Publicized address: 10.42.21.233
[gzclient --verbose  -2] [Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[ERROR] [ros2-4]: process[ros2-4] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[ERROR] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: process[gzclient --verbose  -2] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [ros2-4]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[ros2-4]
[INFO] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gzclient --verbose  -2]
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gzserver-1]
[ERROR] [gzclient --verbose  -2]: process has died [pid 305727, exit code -15, cmd 'gzclient --verbose  '].
[ERROR] [ros2-4]: process has died [pid 305733, exit code -15, cmd 'ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -entity bed -z 0.375 -Y 1.57 -file /home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_simulation/share/ysio_simulation/models/PatientBed/model.sdf'].
[gzclient --verbose  -2] 
[gzclient --verbose  -2] 
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 305725, exit code -15, cmd 'gzserver /home/ros/test_mig_ws/src/install/ysio_simulation/share/ysio_simulation/worlds/simulation.world      --verbose                                                                -s libgazebo_ros_init.so   -s libgazebo_ros_factory.so   -s libgazebo_ros_force_system.so       '].
[gzserver-1] 
[gzserver-1] 

Thank you

The error
RuntimeError('Failed to handle type {...}') 

suggests that there is an issue with the parameter type in your configuration. Specifically, the parameter structure for the YSIO::ysio_controller is not being handled correctly by the normalize_parameter_dict function. Make sure the parameter file's (.yaml?) structure is correct. At runtime, it is parsed and the resulting dictionary seems to be corrupt. Probably an indent error or similar?

I have found a small syntax error in the configuration file in the following part:
controller_list:
  - name: YSIO::ysio_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:

the dash before the "name" part, when i removed it, the file was recognized and correctly, and for some reason, the gazebo process did not die any more and kept running.
however, I received other errors and I am dealing with them at the moment.
